# When there is a namespace conflict, how do I tell Compiler / JVM which jar to look for a certain Class in JBoss Web Application?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss5.x, hornetq

I am building a Web App using JBoss 5.0 that connects to JMS Queues and Topics on the same server I am deploying the application to. I ran into an issue where i am getting the following error.

```
ConnectionFactory tfact = (ConnectionFactory) cntxt.lookup(p.getProperty("topicFactory"));

 ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQQueueConnectionFactory cannot be cast to javax.jms.ConnectionFactory
  ERROR [STDERR]    at com.delegation.AgentDelegator.<init>(AgentDelegator.java:48)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at com.ui.properties.OnStartupServlet.init(OnStartupServlet.java:50)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1048)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:950)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4122)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4417)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:313)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:145)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:122)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:297)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1454)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1172)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1193)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1113)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:789)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:699)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:403)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:778)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:543)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.registerProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:308)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:256)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:229)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.Main$1.call(Main.java:561)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at org.jboss.Main$1.call(Main.java:557)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
  ERROR [STDERR]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I run the same code on a different machine and it works fine.... I noticed in the JBoss libraries that I am importing there are two jar files that have org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQQueueConnectionFactory. One is called hornetq-jms.jar and the other is hornetq-jms-client.jar. My assumption is that on one machine, I am using the class from one jar and on the other, i am using the other jar. I have been told that which jar it goes to depends on the order in my classpath. If this is the case, my questions is: how do i change the classpath of the war file? If not my questions are:
1.) How do i find out which one i am using?
2.) how do i change which one i use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that the older JAR is supplied by JBoss and the newer JAR is a transient dependency?

Comment: This falls in the category of It doesn't work, please help me!
It's probably a dependency mistake and it's impossible for us to do your debug. I didn't vote you negative.. but you certainly would deserve lots of negative votes. Please add some context and some debug and someone will help you (I bet you would probably find the issue yourself if you did some more debug)

Comment: i think i know the issue. its that i have two jars that cause a namespace conflict. my question is, how do i tell the compiler (or jvm) which one to use?

Comment: Alvin, no, both jars are supplied by jboss. one is $JBOSS_HOME/jboss-as/client/hornetq-jms-client.jar and the other is $JBOSS_HOME/jboss-as/common/lib/hornetq-jms.jar

Comment: @Clebert, i dont see why you think this deserves negative votes. if i was asking what i was doing wrong, then yes, but i am not asking that. I am asking how to find out which jar file i am referencing. since you are a hornetq expert, i guess you would know if one of those jars contains a HornetQQueueConnectionFactory class that for some odd reason does not implement javax.jms.ConnectionFactory. so if that is not my issue, then the answer to my question wont help me, but nonetheless, the question is valid

Comment: @AlvinThompson I'm not the one who voted -1. 
How to find these jars? by reading your classpath and debuging it.. there's no magic on that.. and I don't see how anyone would be able to help you here. 
Besides this kind of thing could happen to anything in java as long as you messed up jars.

We could help you if you provided an easy way to replicate this issue. Even so it would be a consulting engagement almost but we can try our best. Use the HornetQ user's forum if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you configure your connection factory correctly?

According to https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/pdf/HornetQ_User_Guide/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform-5-HornetQ_User_Guide-en-US.pdf you have to configure your connection factory with `signature=generic` to retrieve a javax.jms.ConnectionFactory:

```
<connection-factory name="ConnectionFactory" signature="generic">
```

Another question is what `p.getProperty("topicFactory")` points to. Does the value come from some external resource that is not part of the application?